# how to add multiple foreign keys into the same row in Many to many in Ecto

Tags: many-to-many, elixir, ecto

Is it possible to insert multiple many to many relations at one? for example I have an AccessList table which has company_id, user_id, role_id, asset_id, and project_id

They are all many to many. AccessList is the reference table.

Here is the schema for the AccessList

```
 schema "access_lists" do
        belongs_to :user, Db.User
        belongs_to :role, Db.Role
        belongs_to :asset, Db.Asset
        belongs_to :project, Db.Project
        belongs_to :company, Db.Company

        timestamps()
    end
```

Here is the company schema as an example:

```
 many_to_many :users, Db.User, join_through: Db.AccessList
        many_to_many :assets, Db.Asset, join_through: Db.AccessList 
        many_to_many :roles, Db.Role, join_through: Db.AccessList 
        many_to_many :projects, Db.Project, join_through: Db.AccessList
```

At the moment for example if a request comes in I will, get the user, role, and company, then I create the asset and I insert their IDs at once into AccessList.

Sample:

```
def create_asset_relation(role, asset, user, company) do
        changeset = create_asset_changeset( %{user_id: user.id, role_id: role.id, company_id: company.id, asset_id: asset.id})

       with {:ok, _ } <- Repo.insert(changeset) do
            {:ok, asset}
       else
            _ ->
                "something gone wrong"
        end
    end

    defp create_asset_changeset(params) do
        AccessList.changeset(%AccessList{}, params)
    end
```

Comment: What is your problem? The code does not work? Insert is not happening?

Comment: My code works fine. In my Rails time I used to use ActiveRecord, and push these things in the DB without needing to get all of the references and insert them in the reference table. I thought there could be a better way of doing this, so I asked.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to insert multiple many to many relations at one?

Yes, your code example resembles the [join schema example](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#many_to_many/3-join-schema-example) from the documentation:

```
defmodule UserOrganization do
  use Ecto.Schema

  @primary_key false
  schema "users_organizations" do
    belongs_to :user, User
    belongs_to :organization, Organization
    timestamps # Added bonus, a join schema will also allow you to set timestamps
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> Ecto.Changeset.cast(params, [:user_id, :organization_id])
    |> Ecto.Changeset.validate_required([:user_id, :organization_id])
    # Maybe do some counter caching here!
  end
end

defmodule User do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "users" do
    many_to_many :organizations, Organization, join_through: UserOrganization
  end
end

defmodule Organization do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "organizations" do
    many_to_many :users, User, join_through: UserOrganization
  end
end

# Then to create the association, pass in the ID's of an existing
# User and Organization to UserOrganization.changeset
changeset = UserOrganization.changeset(%UserOrganization{}, %{user_id: id, organization_id: id})

case Repo.insert(changeset) do
  {:ok, assoc} -> # Assoc was created!
  {:error, changeset} -> # Handle the error
end
```

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing, I thought I might be able to use `put_assoc` or something like that. If you see my code, I insert `Asset` then I get the return `id` and insert in the reference table with all the references